# Looper.loop is ignored in approximately 20% cases

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a worker thread that is running in the background. On this worker thread, I have a method called syncWithUiThreadAndWait. Here is the simplified code:

```
    private void syncWithUiThreadAndWait(final Runnable codeToSync) {
        if (looper == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread is not ready (Looper=null)");
        if (looper != Looper.myLooper())
            throw new RuntimeException("Called from wrong thread");
        final boolean[] wasRun = {false};
        new Handler(looper).post(new Runnable() {
            // I use 'new Handler(looper).post' instead of direct call to make sure that this code will
            // run 100% after Looper.loop() is called, because in some cases it can be called before Looper.loop
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (MyWorkerThread.this) {
                            // Synchronization to establishes a happens-before relationship
                            wasRun[0] = true;
                            looper.quit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        Looper.loop();
        synchronized (MyWorkerThread.this) {
            // Synchronization to establishes a happens-before relationship
            if (!wasRun[0]) 
                throw new RuntimeException("WHY!!!");
        }
    }
```

So my question is: why sometimes this code runs correctly and sometimes thread loop does not start and I receive my 'WHY' exception?

**Edit:**
I decided to add some explanation to make it easier to understand.
What I am trying to do is a synchronized thread with UI thread.

1. First, prepare task `new Handler (looper) .post (...);` that will be run once I 'block' my background thread from continuing.
2. After that, I 'block' my background thread by `Looper.loop ();`
3. The task that I prepared will run once the loop is looped and will fire code for UI thread.
4. Lastly, at the end of the code that will be run on UI thread `looper.quit ();` is called to unblock background thread.

Comment: Better not synchronize on Thread object.

Comment: @JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing Why not, how is it different from any other object, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

So even though I still don't know why it was happening. So if someone can explain I will mark it as a correct answer.

But I found a workaround using Thread.sleep() instead of using Looper.loop(). Wich works for me and probably is more efficient:

```
private void syncWithUiThreadAndWait(final Runnable codeToSync) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (thread == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread not ready");
        if (Thread.currentThread() != thread)
            throw new RuntimeException("Called from wrong thread");
    }
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            codeToSync.run();
            setPaused(false);
        }
    });
    setPaused(true);
    final long sleepStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (isPaused()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
        if (sleepStart + TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISEC <= System.currentTimeMillis())
            throw new RuntimeException("Timeout waiting for network response");
    }
}

private synchronized boolean isPaused() {
    return paused;
}

private synchronized void setPaused(boolean newValue) {
    paused = newValue;
}
```